# MacOS BASH, Get output from networkQuality command running in background

Tags: bash, macos

I am trying to launch **networkQuality** command in the background and live fetch the first part of the output to the bash script launching it.

First part I want to fetch from the background command:

**current download capacity: 49.342 Mbps - current upload capacity: 52.951 Mbps**

Code:

```
networkQuality &
```

When the command have finished in the background I also want to fetch the result:

**==== SUMMARY ====**
**Upload capacity: 68.877 Mbps**

**Download capacity: 67.388 Mbps**

**Upload flows: 16**

**Download flows: 20**

Anyway of doing this?

Comment: I'd suggest you redirect networkQuality's output to a file. That makes it easier to access the data you want to parse: `networkQuality > /path/to/log/file 2>&1 &`

Comment: This only get me the final summary. Not the live speed test result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following call to get verbose data with all the raw data in JSON format...

```
networkquality -v -c
```